Change SwiftUI iOS DatePicker button style
I have a DatePicker in a form:
import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                DatePicker("Pick a date", selection: $date)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Content()
}

which will give me:

The default displays the DatePicker button that launches the actual picker as the selected date in a gray box. Is there a way to change the size, shape and color of the DatePicker button?

have you tried using DatePickerStyle, eg .datePickerStyle(...)

My understanding is that .datePickerStyle(...) controls the style of picker being used. For instance .datePickerStyle(.wheel) changes it to the wheel picker instead of the default calendar picker.

This answer might help: SwiftUI: Compact DatePicker with custom design
